# DB2 : Grant all privileges to db2admin on the localhost database

Tags: java, db2

I have installed DB2 Express-C on my local machine and sample database is created for my username.
Now, I want db2admin to access this sample database.
I have tried below command,

```
connect to DATABASENAME user USER_NAME using USER_PASSWORD

GRANT DBADM,CREATETAB,BINDADD,CONNECT,CREATE_NOT_FENCED_ROUTINE,IMPLICIT_SCHEMA,LOAD,CREATE_EXTERNAL_ROUTINE,QUIESCE_CONNECT,SECADM ON DATABASE TO USER DB2ADMIN;
```

But then too, I am unable to access the database tables using db2admin as shown below,

```
connect to DATABASENAME user db2admin using USER_PASSWORD

list tables
```

It is displaying 0 record found. That means it is not able to access the database.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does "unable to access" means? Any error messages or codes?

Comment: A User can't grant any privileges that the user account doesn't have.

Comment: I have edited the code for detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

> That means it is not able to access the database.

Wrong.
DB2 would tell you that already when you connected.
Your example merely shows that user db2admin has no tables in his default schema.

Try this:

```
list tables for schema user_name
```

where `user_name` is the name of the db creator.

Note that

```
list tables
```

lists the tables for the current user, and will return 0 rows until you create some.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the following steps: (Here I'll use SAMPLE as an example)

1. connect to SAMPLE using your windows domain ID:

   `db2 connect to SAMPLE`

   Here, the connection will use your windows domain ID by default. And you check this by return "SQL authorization ID = "
2. `db2 grant DATAACCESS on DATABASE to user db2admin`

   This will grant `DATAACCESS` authority to `db2admin`
3. Terminate connection: `db2 terminate`
4. Connect to SAMPLE with db2admin: `db2 connect to sample user db2admin using 'password'`
5. You should be able to access db with your `db2admin`

You can read more about windows domain ID and db2admin here:

1. [IBM Data Studio can't browse data on SAMPLE (DB2 Express-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929634/ibm-data-studio-cant-browse-data-on-sample-db2-express-c)
2. [How do I grant all privileges to local db2admin with DB2 9.7 on Windows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/how-do-i-grant-all-privileges-to-local-db2admin-with-db2-9-7-on-windows)

Please let me know how it works.